# Get last of a group

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have a table in mySQL which tracks the changes of certain datums. It looks like such:

```
id | person_id | datum        | value   | changed_on | 
=======================================================
1  | 1         | 'first_name' | 'Jane'  | 2018-06-12 | 
-------------------------------------------------------
2  | 1         | 'last_name'  | 'Smith' | 2018-06-12 | 
-------------------------------------------------------
3  | 1         | 'age'        | '29'    | 2018-06-12 | 
-------------------------------------------------------
4  | 1         | 'is_married' | '0'     | 2018-06-12 | 
-------------------------------------------------------
5  | 1         | 'is_married' | '1'     | 2018-07-28 | 
-------------------------------------------------------
6  | 1         | 'last_name'  | 'Blow'  | 2018-07-28 | 
-------------------------------------------------------
(repeat for other person_ids, etc.)
(ignore the fact that 29, 0 and 1 are technically text which is not optimal, I know)
```

I am trying to get the last `datum` for each `person_id`. Could be transposed but doesn't have to be. I did some research and [came across one method](https://paulund.co.uk/get-last-record-in-each-mysql-group) of getting the latest row (by `changed_on`). For me that's:

```
select *
from changes
where id in (
  select max(id)
  from changes
  group by person_id, datum
);
```

It does work, however is matching on the `id`, whereas I want to match it on `changed_on` (as the latest change might not be the latest `id`). I was thinking of doing something like:

```
select *
from changes
where id in (
  select id, max(changed_on)
  from changes
  group by person_id, datum
); /* somehow need the id of the max change */
```

But obviously you cannot return multiple columns in this scenario. Somehow I need to get the `id`s of the rows returned from `max(changed_on)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are aiming for:

```
select c.*
from changes c
where (person_id, datum, changed_on) in (
          (select c2.person_id, c2.datum, max(c2.changed_on)
           from changes c2
           group by c2.person_id, c2.datum
          );
```